# iterate through multiple document with certain doc id from a collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, ecmascript-6

hope you are coding well, I am using firebase and vue js to build a messenger application.
Each user has a document, and within each document there is a field named includeInMsg, which contains the Id of the message that the user included. I know how to read one document by its id, but I don't know how to read multiple documents by their ids.
here you can see my code:

```js
import { ref } from "vue";
import { db } from "src/boot/firebase";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { updateDoc, arrayUnion, arrayRemove } from "firebase/firestore";
import {
  addDoc,
  collection,
  query,
  where,
  getDocs,
  getDoc
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { doc, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      userList: ref([]),
      userMessageRefList: ref([]),
      userMessageDocList: ref([]),
      freelancerProfile: ref([]),
      messages: ref([]),
      userMessage: ref([]),
      listofdata: ref([])
    };
  },
  async created() {
    // check if user loged in or not
    const auth = getAuth();
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
      if (user) {
        // store current user uid in userlist
        this.userList.unshift(user.uid);
        this.renderMessageList();
      } else {
        this.$router.push("/");
      }
    });
  },
  methods: {
    // render user message list doc id
    async renderMessageList() {
      const currentUserProfile = query(
        collection(db, "userProfile"),
        where("uuid", "==", this.userList[0])
      );
      const userProfileQuerySnapshot = await getDocs(currentUserProfile);
      userProfileQuerySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        let docData = doc.data();
        this.userMessageRefList.unshift(docData.messageList);
        this.listofdata.unshift(docData);
      });
      this.userMessageRefList.forEach(elem =>
        // store doc id into userMessageDocList
        elem.forEach(le => this.userMessageDocList.unshift(le))
      );
      console.log(this.userMessageDocList) //output: {0: {…}, 1: {…}}
      // now I need to read each document by their doc Id and store it in an array to render

    },
  },
  computed: {
    checkMessages: function() {
      if (this.messages.length > 1) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I tried to use for loop to read each document and store the value in an array but I got `SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word 'await'. (71:26)` error.

Comment: Do I correctly understand that `this.userMessageDocList` contains a compounded object containing objects with the documents IDs?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As confirmed in the comments, `this.userMessageDocList` contains a compounded object containing objects with the documents IDs.

In this case you should use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to trigger a variable number of calls to Firestore in parallel.

As explained in the doc (see link above):

> The `Promise.all()` method takes an **iterable** of promises as an
> input, and returns a single Promise **that resolves to an array of the
> results** of the input promises.

---

So you need to loop over the object, grab the Docs IDs and populate an Array of Promises that you pass to `Promise.all()`. In pseudo code (I let you use the method you want to loop over the object, there are a lot of examples on SO) it's something along the following lines:

```
const promisesArray = [];

<Loop For each element>
   // Assumption: element.docId contains the Firestore doc ID
   promisesArray.push(getDoc(doc(db, "yourCollection", element.docId)))

</End Loop>

const docSnapshotsArray = await Promise.all(promisesArray);
docSnapshotsArray.forEach(docSnap => {
   console.log(docSnap.data());
   // ...
});
```

`docSnapshotsArrays` is an Array of [`DocumentSnapshot`s](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentsnapshot). You can then loop over this array and do whatever you want.

---

I don't now if this is important for your specific case, but note that with `Promise.all()`,  the **returned values in the resulting Array will be in order of the Promises passed**, regardless of completion order.

Comment: Hey @PooyaPanahandeh did you have time to look at the proposed solution?